# How To find .c for the executable from which it is obtained?

Tags: c, linux

If I have 3-4 .c files or more in a directory and I have compiled one of them to make executable `a.out`. Is there any way possible to find out through command, from which c file this executable was obtained?

Comment: How do you know it wasn't built from *all* of them? Or none of them?

Comment: Compile all the .c files with all the different options for your compiler then compare the resulting executables to the first a.out file.

Comment: Wby not run the program and observe its behaviour? Surely then you can determine the original C code

Comment: If you compiled with debugging symbols you can use e.g. objdump -g to find out.

Comment: Run `strings` on the executable and look for a unique text.

Comment: Write a Help function to your executables ? Like : `executable -?` in which you can put any info you want.

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly. The only metadata that the file has left is its [ELF headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header), which do not include the name of the .c file it was compiled from. It would be problematic if they did: what if it came from multiple .c files? Would it include paths to binaries on the system that it was linked against? What would happen if you renamed the .c files? Would renaming a .c file need to trigger a recompilation?

That aside, there are a number of ways you could figure it out: run the executable and compare it against the .c files, or try compiling each of the .c files and comparing the two executables (assuming you know what flags the executable was compiled with).

Answer (score 1):

I think that in general there is no way to figure out (exactly) from which source files an executable comes. You can look at the behaviour of the executable and say "aha, its from that file" but that isn't absolute because there can be multiple versions of the source file. Other arguments have been given already such as compiling the source and comparing the binaries, which requires all the compiler options to be set identical (and requires that al libraries are the same too).

Lastly you can look at the strings in the binary and compare those to the strings in the source files.